# Android AppBarLayout height more than screen height

Tags: android, drawerlayout

I am trying to create something like this

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frameAdvertiseSlider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap">

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewPagerAdvertiseSlider"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/pager_advertise_slider_height"
                android:layout_gravity="top" />

            <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
                android:id="@+id/indicatorAdvertiseSlider"
                style="@style/IntroPageIndicator"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_medium" />

        </FrameLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayoutMainCategory"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_mini_small"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonMainCategory1"
                style="@style/ButtonHomeStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_category"
                android:paddingBottom="12dp"
                android:paddingTop="15dp"
                android:text="@string/home_category_category" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonMainCategory2"
                style="@style/ButtonHomeStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_action"
                android:paddingTop="15dp"
                android:text="@string/home_category_action" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonMainCategory3"
                style="@style/ButtonHomeStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_new"
                android:paddingTop="15dp"
                android:text="@string/home_category_new" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonMainCategory4"
                style="@style/ButtonHomeStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_most_selling"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:text="@string/home_category_most_selling" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayoutBanners"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_mini_small"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_mini_small"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageBanner1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/banner1_height"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/banner1_height"
                android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageBanner2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/banner2_height"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="#00000000" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageBanner3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/banner2_height"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_mini_small">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabLayoutNews"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/tabs_height"
                android:background="@color/white"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/main_color"
                app:tabMode="fixed"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/home_tab_color"
                app:tabTextColor="@color/home_tab_color" />

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewPagerNews"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/news_pager_height"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayoutPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/tabs_height"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:tabGravity="center"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/main_color"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/home_tab_color"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/home_tab_color" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewPagerTabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/home_profile_background" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearProfile"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_medium"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <rs.netlink.android.widgets.CircleImageView
                    android:id="@+id/circleImageViewProfile"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/profile_image_size"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/profile_image_size"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/default_profile_image"
                    app:border_color="@color/home_profile_image_ellipse"
                    app:border_width="1dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_small_medium"
                    android:textColor="@color/home_profile_image_ellipse"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_small_normal" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textEmail"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_mini_small"
                    android:textColor="@color/home_profile_image_ellipse"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_micro_mini" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_small">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonMenuHome"
                    style="@style/ButtonHomeMenuBorderlessWhite"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_menu_home"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_menu_home"
                    android:text="@string/menu_home" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonMenuProfile"
                    style="@style/ButtonHomeMenuBorderlessWhite"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_menu_profile"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_menu_profile"
                    android:text="@string/menu_profile" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonMenuBasket"
                    style="@style/ButtonHomeMenuBorderlessWhite"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_menu_basket"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_menu_basket"
                    android:text="@string/menu_basket" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonMenuWishList"
                    style="@style/ButtonHomeMenuBorderlessWhite"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_menu_wish_list"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_menu_wish_list"
                    android:text="@string/menu_wish_list" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonMenuWhereToBay"
                    style="@style/ButtonHomeMenuBorderlessWhite"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_where_to_bay"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_where_to_bay"
                    android:text="@string/menu_where_to_buy" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"
                    android:background="@color/home_menu_separator_line" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonMenuSettings"
                    style="@style/ButtonHomeMenuBorderlessWhite"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_menu_settings"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_menu_settings"
                    android:text="@string/menu_settings" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonMenuCallCenter"
                    style="@style/ButtonHomeMenuBorderlessWhite"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_call_center"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_call_center"
                    android:text="@string/menu_call_centar" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonMenuAboutUs"
                    style="@style/ButtonHomeMenuBorderlessWhite"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_about_us"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_about_us"
                    android:text="@string/menu_about_us" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonMenuTerms"
                    style="@style/ButtonHomeMenuBorderlessWhite"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_terms"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_terms"
                    android:text="@string/menu_terms" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

When I try this content in AppBarLayout is showed how much is screen height. When I set DrawerLayout `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` it does not work. How to resolve this.

Thanks.

Comment: I used smooth-app-bar-layout it's solved my problem  https://github.com/henrytao-me/smooth-app-bar-layout

Answer (score 0):

You would want the closing tag `</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>` after the include toolbar and not where you have it after a linear layout. The way you have it is including most of what you define here in your `AppBarLayout` instead of below it, which is not what I think you are try to do.

Comment: That didn't fix my problem. I don't see all content in AppBarLayout.